# Is finding a three way hash collision infeasible

Tags: hash, birthday-attack

Is there an equivalent to the birthday paradox for more than 2 messages.

Solving `Hash(x) = 0` takes $2^{bits}$ steps on average

Solving `Hash(x) XOR Hash(y) = 0` takes around $2 ^{bits/2}$ due to the birthday paradox.

Is there an algorithm that can solve `Hash(x) XOR Hash(y) XOR Hash(z) = 0` in $2^{bits/3}$ steps (or similar)?

If so, does it get easier to find a solution if you add more terms?

[edit]
The second post by Squeamish Ossifrage is what I was looking for, thanks.

Comment: Actually, I guess this is more like https://crypto.stackexchange.com/q/48333 since $H(x) + H(y) + H(z) = 0$ is not the same as $H(x) = H(y) = H(z)$, which is what the Joux multicollisions paper is about.  See [Wagner's generalized birthday paper](https://people.eecs.berkeley.edu/~daw/papers/genbday.html) for more details.

Comment: Here is the [first link](https://crypto.stackexchange.com/questions/10762/three-way-hash-collision) provided from Squeamish, which is a similar question but not a complete dupe.

Comment: Further, note that solving the 3XORSUM problem $H(x) \oplus H(y) \oplus H(z) =0$ is open, in the sense of finding an algorithm with complexity less than $2^{n/2},$ and approaching $2^{n/3}.$ Wagner's algorithm gives relatively efficient solutions for $k$ a power of two, when we consider $H(x_1)\oplus H(x_2) \oplus \cdots \oplus H(x_k)=0.$

Comment: See the following related questions to 3XORSUM. https://cstheory.stackexchange.com/questions/37233/implications-of-an-tildeon1-5-3xorsum-algorithm and https://cstheory.stackexchange.com/questions/42246/violas-reduction-of-3xor-to-listing-triangles